# Waiting for Loader

Tags: actionscript-3

*Edit:  Looks like I typoed today.  Thanks, Antoine.*

I need to fetch the published dimensions of any given swf.  Until now, I've relied on loaderInfo for this, however, I've recently discovered that those properties are not fully loaded even after `this` is `addedToStage`.  Checking if `loaderInfo.hasOwnProperty("width")` is pointless, as the property already exists, but that property itself is a getter function which returns the error.  Therefore, to avoid a [Error #2099](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/runtimeErrors.html#2099), I'm querying a property that only shows after being fully loaded, and doing it inside a try/catch statement.  Problem is... the catch isn't... catching?

```
var loaderLoaded:Boolean = false;
try { loaderLoaded = (this.loaderInfo.width > 0) ? true : false; } catch (e:Event) {}
trace("Loader loaded: " + loaderLoaded);
```

As stated before, this results with

`Error #2099: The loading object is not sufficiently loaded to provide this information. at flash.display::LoaderInfo/get width()`

I need to either fix the try/catch statement, or find another way of polling swf dimensions.

Comment: Can you not access the info even after the Event.COMPLETE has been fired?  I would attempt handling it that way instead of using the try catch block, perhaps since .width isn't a direct method invocation your catch isn't being called when the error is thrown from the internally invoked method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just copy/pasted this, you wrote `catch(e:Event)` instead of `catch(e:Error)`.

You cannot catch an event.

Comment: Wow, yeah, I didn't realize I typoed.  That would explain why it wasn't catching.  Thanks for that.  :)